# PHP form with radio buttons - make only one answer required, second optional

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have this PHP form with radio buttons:

```
{
$agreements = jm_get_application_setting( 'application_agreements', '' );
if( empty( $agreements ) ) return;

$questions = explode( "\n", $agreements );
if (!empty($questions)):
    foreach ($questions as $index => $question) :
        ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p><strong for="question-<?php echo sanitize_title($question); ?>" ><?php echo $question; ?></strong></p>
            <div class="form-control-flat">
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="_noo_application_answer_<?php echo $index; ?>" value="1" required><i></i><?php echo esc_html__('Do il consenso', 'noo'); ?>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control-flat">
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="_noo_application_answer_<?php echo $index; ?>" value="0" required><i></i><?php echo esc_html__('Nego il consenso', 'noo'); ?>
                </label>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="_noo_questions[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($question); ?>"/>
        </div>

        <?php
    endforeach;
endif;

}
```

How can I make only one answer required to validate the form?

I mean.. Just the first MUST be selected, but I also need to show the second one for "legal reasons".

As is, this form accepts both choices as acceptable.

Comment: If you need more than one answer use Checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable for the condition, and change it's value at the end of first iteration.

```
if (!empty($questions)):
    $first = 1; // <----- HERE
    foreach ($questions as $index => $question) :
        ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <p><strong for="question-<?php echo sanitize_title($question); ?>" ><?php echo $question; ?></strong></p>
            <div class="form-control-flat">
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" 
                           name="_noo_application_answer_<?php echo $index; ?>"            
                           value="1" 
                           <?php echo $first ? "required" : ""; ?>> // <----- HERE
                           <i></i><?php echo esc_html__('Do il consenso', 'noo'); ?>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-control-flat">
                <label class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" 
                           name="_noo_application_answer_<?php echo $index; ?>"
                           value="0" 
                           <?php echo $first ? "required" : ""; ?>> // <----- HERE
                           <i></i><?php echo esc_html__('Nego il consenso', 'noo'); ?>
                </label>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="_noo_questions[]" value="<?php echo esc_attr($question); ?>"/>
        </div>

        <?php
    $first = 0; // <----- HERE
    endforeach;
endif;
```